# WPF Canvas stops redraw after ScaleTransform

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, canvas, rendertransform

We are using a WPF Canvas for showing a map of rooms in a hotel in time.

It is possible to move with it using scroll bars, this is done by TranslateTransform of that canvas. It is even possible to zoom it, which is done by ScaleTransform of the canvas. The users can select a block in that map, which is normally done by:

```
Rectangle
Canvas.Children.Add
Canvas.SetLeft
Canvas.SetTop
```

But it seems there is a bug in the Canvas when it's tranasformed, because it stops render a new content (that block selecting for instance) which is added after that transformation. I know that the new content is really added to canvas, because it is suddenly visible when user sets the scale back to 1 (no scale). The problem is visible on scales < 1, probably when the canvas gets more objects to draw.

I was trying to force the canvas to redraw by ArrangeOverride or UpdateLayout in that transformed situation, but it doesn't help.

So does anyone know what's going on and how to workaround it? The help would be much appreciated.

Thank you.

**Edit:**

I prepared a MCVE on GitHub here:
https://github.com/kanovsky/CanvasTest

When I had this example I confirmed my conjecture that the bug appears when there is a lot of elements in the canvas, so there is not problem with the ScaleTransform.

The whole control is based on this article:
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31661/Much-Faster-Silverlight-Scrolling

Works without problems in Silverlight and recently was moved to WPF, where this bug appeared.

Comment: How are you adding new items to the canvas? Are you doing it from a background thread?

Comment: It would also be helpful if you could provide us with an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Clint Everything on UI thread, otherwise it wouldn't work.

Comment: Have you tried template binding a `FreezableCollection` as the `ItemSource` of an ItemControl using your `Canvas` as an `ItemPanel` instead of adding them directly ? (Then clone and replace the whole collection on change as it is freezable). It shouldn't have a big performance impact from my tests.

Comment: Which transform have you used? There are two. Try [another one](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.layouttransform(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @Clint: I would like, but basically there in nothing more than setting of ScaleTransform of Canvas, then adding Rectangle to that canvas.

Comment: @tomasK I've put a LINQPAD query here: https://gist.github.com/ckpearson/c4225bdd4d0bff51dfd70b2d6703c019 which when run does not exhibit your problem.

Comment: @Clint: Like that, only more content in that canvas, but I can try to reproduce it in this way. It even doesn't fail always in each scale, but rather when there is more elements in the canvas and it's more zoomed out.

Comment: Are you certain it's *not* working? Could it just be that it's zoomed out sufficiently enough that the item added doesn't show up (due to scaling?); what do you see if you examine the visual/logical tree in visual studio (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd409789.aspx) - do they show up in the tree?

Comment: I am trying it now and it is definitely in the visual tree, the canvas is only still showing the older version of itself.

Comment: @tomasK can you share the code that is producing the effect?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151411/discussion-between-tomask-and-clint).